# ODE with no solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE
$$y''+16y=0$$
with $y(0)=y_0$ and $y(\pi/2)=y_1$, I have to find for which $y_0$ and $y_1$, the ODE will have none solution.

I know there are $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$y(t)=A\cos(4t)+B\sin(4t)$$
and when I use the initial conditions, I get
$$y_1=y_0=A$$
Hence
$$y(t)=y_0\cos(4t)+B\sin(4t)$$
However, I have any clue for what I should do now.

Comment: Simply the ODE has no solution when $y_0\neq y_1$.

Comment: Usually the second condition is for $y'$ for second order ode. Maybe there is a typo?

Comment: @Vasili : There is a difference between initial-value problems (IVP) and boundary-value problems (BVP). The latter can have value combinations with no or infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're done!  You've proved that any solution to the ODE must have $y_0 = y_1$; and conversely if $y_0 \neq y_1$, no solutions exist.

The fact that $B$ remains undetermined in the solution means that multiple solutions exist when $y_0 = y_1$;  but that's not important if you're being asked the question, "for which values of $y_0$ and $y_1$ do *any* solutions exist?"